# Excel VBA Using MS Access DB Should I close connection?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm creating an Excel VBA program for people at my office. The way I intend it to work is each person will have their own "portal", an Excel document where they can interact with the DB with their own user settings. This way there won't be issues with multiple people trying to use an Excel file at the same time.

The thing I'm not sure about is the Access Database I'm setting up. It's a single DB file that everyone can access. Currently the plan is to create the connection this way:

```
Dim accessFileLoc As String: accessFileLoc = "C:\Users\gmloo\OneDrive\Desktop\Grab Project\GrabDB.accdb"

'create the connection object, and open the connection
Set accessCon = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

'i HOPE setting the mode like this will allow multiple users to connect to the same
'db at the same time
accessCon.Mode = 16 + 3 'adModeShareDenyNone + adModeShareReadWrite
accessCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFileLoc
```

accessCon is a global Excel VBA variable that is currently designed to hold the connection as long as the Excel program is open. My question is, will this cause problems with other users all Querying the DB file at the same time? Should I be closing the connection for each user while it isnt needed, then re-establish it when they have to do a query? There's probably going to be up to 15 people using their Excel portal at any given time.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Multiple Excel connections should not be an issue. If it were, Access could not be a multi-user app.

Comment: So multiple users are connecting to a single access database located on one of the person's C: and each person has it referenced to their own C: ? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with multiple users connecting at the same time. However, due to memory and performance issues, I would recommend you close the connection after each query.